# RabbitMQ Round Robin

Tags: go, rabbitmq, amqp

I am trying to build a system where a master service creates a bunch of messages and routes them to the correct queue based on the routing key. I have that working and the messages are being consumed on the worker/slave side. However I want the worker to only take one message from the queue and not all 15 that get put into it.

I was looking at this https://github.com/streadway/amqp/blob/master/channel.go#L616 however I am not sure how to set it up so only one event is taken.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I haven't worked with the Go AMQP client, but the AMQP protocol semantics should be universal across client implementations, so I'll take a shot.

---

You've already correctly identified the `prefetch-size` and `prefetch-count` parameters as the configuration variables to adjust. The [RabbitMQ documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html) says the following in this regard:<sup>1</sup>

> AMQP specifies the `basic.qos` method to allow you to **limit the number of unacknowledged messages** on a channel (or connection) when consuming (aka "prefetch count").

If you want each consumer to be sent only one message at a time, you should set `prefetch-count` to 1, and leave `prefetch-size` undefined (i.e. 0):

```
err := channel.Qos(1, 0, false)
if err != nil {
    // ...
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>
There's also a longer description in [RabbitMQ's AMQP reference](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html) on this one:

> **long prefetch-size**
>
> The client can request that messages be sent in advance so that when the client finishes processing a message, the following message is already held locally, rather than needing to be sent down the channel. *[...]* The server will send a message in advance if it is equal to or smaller in size than the available prefetch size (and also falls into other prefetch limits). **May be set to zero, meaning "no specific limit", although other prefetch limits may still apply.** The prefetch-size is ignored if the no-ack option is set.
>
> *[...]*
>
> **short prefetch-count**
>
> Specifies a prefetch window in terms of whole messages. This field may be used in combination with the prefetch-size field; a message will only be sent in advance if both prefetch windows (and those at the channel and connection level) allow it. *[...]*